# How can I render different content in a marketing cloud email based on the device type?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dynamic-content

In the email body I have different content I want to show based on whether the device is android or iOS, is there an attribute available to create dynamic content for this logic?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have it stored inside of a DE that person X always (or as close to always as you can get) opens your emails via an android device - you will need to go the same route as everyone else, relying on CSS media queries - which is not always supported.

If you have the data - you will need to have all the content inside the email using a conditional in AMPScript to differentiate which gets displayed depending on if person x has value of Android or iOS.

Otherwise you can only use CSS media queries - which aren't always that reliable and usually require quite a bit of extra effort. Some good resources are via [Litmus](https://litmus.com/blog/understanding-media-queries-in-html-email) and [EmailMonks](https://emailmonks.com/blog/email-coding/show-hide-device-specific-content/).

If it is just whether you want a specific image to display, you can make images more targeted via paid services like [Movable Ink](https://movableink.com/) or DIY options (something like [this](https://github.com/Omgitsonlyalex/EmailCountdown) - but this is aimed more at countdown clocks, but logic can be the same.)

Comment: `Email on Acid` is another 3rd party service that does previews & spam testing